# Resizing TextView does not shrink its height on Android 3.1

Tags: android, resize, textview

I have a `TextView` which can be resized dinamically (I use `setTextSize()`). It correctly expands and shrinks its bounds on Android 2.2. But on Android 3.1, when the text become smaller, the height of area is not shrink.

[Here is the short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQ3DztnoxMA&feature=player_embedded) that demonstrates that.

The layout is just simple vertical `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="0dip">
... 
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/track_number" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/tcTrackNo" 
    android:padding="5dp" />
    ...


<style name="tcTrackNo" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/track_number</item>
</style>
```

So, what extra should be done to make the `TextView` reduce its height accordingly to its font size on Honeycomb?

PS. Again, on Android 2.2 the text area collapses until the smallest height without any issue. [The video how it's intended to work](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq2noqd64Ws).

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late it's from a bug

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17343

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22493

But there is a workaround by appending a non width character at the end of your text.

Any of these work

```
final String DOUBLE_BYTE_SPACE = "\u3000";
final String DOUBLE_BYTE_WORDJOINER = "\u2060";
final String ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE = "\u200b";
textview.append(ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old thread.

but all these characters listed above did not worked properly with me, i faced this issue with 5.0.1 and the fix was to set the textview gravity to center vertical.

hope this help anyone :)